How to add a new stage to an Azure DevOps release using Postman?
I have tried various methods but have not succeeded. I need to add a new stage to a release via Postman, preferably using a template that I already have created in Azure DevOps. I attempted this method
https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organisation}/{project}/_apis/release/definitions/id?api-version=6.0
I need a way to add a new stage to a release.


I need to add a new stage to a release via Postman

To meet your requirement, you need to use this Rest API: Definitions - Update
PUT https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=5.1

For the request body of adding stage, it in fact only made changes into environments parameter:
For example:

Here are the steps:
Stpe1: Run the Rest API: Definitions - Get to get the current Release Pipeline definition.
Step2: Copy the Response value in the Step1. Then you can insert the stage in the environments parameter.
Note: When you updating release, you must pack and set the whole release definition as request body. Get the original one, add new customized stage definition part into it. Then update to api.
Here is an stage example:
{
            "id": -1,
            "name": "Stage 3",
            "rank": 3,
            "variables": {},
            "variableGroups": [],
            "preDeployApprovals": {
                "approvals": [
                    {
                        "rank": 1,
                        "isAutomated": true,
                        "isNotificationOn": false,
                        "id": 7
                    }
                ],
                "approvalOptions": {
                    "requiredApproverCount": null,
                    "releaseCreatorCanBeApprover": false,
                    "autoTriggeredAndPreviousEnvironmentApprovedCanBeSkipped": false,
                    "enforceIdentityRevalidation": false,
                    "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
                    "executionOrder": "beforeGates"
                }
            },
            "deployStep": {
                "id": 8
            },
            "postDeployApprovals": {
                "approvals": [
                    {
                        "rank": 1,
                        "isAutomated": true,
                        "isNotificationOn": false,
                        "id": 9
                    }
                ],
                "approvalOptions": {
                    "requiredApproverCount": null,
                    "releaseCreatorCanBeApprover": false,
                    "autoTriggeredAndPreviousEnvironmentApprovedCanBeSkipped": false,
                    "enforceIdentityRevalidation": false,
                    "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
                    "executionOrder": "afterSuccessfulGates"
                }
            },
            "deployPhases": [
                {
                    "deploymentInput": {
                        "parallelExecution": {
                            "parallelExecutionType": "none"
                        },
                        "agentSpecification": {
                            "identifier": "vs2017-win2016"
                        },
                        "skipArtifactsDownload": false,
                        "artifactsDownloadInput": {
                            "downloadInputs": []
                        },
                        "queueId": 247,
                        "demands": [],
                        "enableAccessToken": false,
                        "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
                        "jobCancelTimeoutInMinutes": 1,
                        "condition": "succeeded()",
                        "overrideInputs": {}
                    },
                    "rank": 1,
                    "phaseType": "agentBasedDeployment",
                    "name": "Agent job",
                    "refName": null,
                    "workflowTasks": []
                }
            ],
            "environmentOptions": {
                "emailNotificationType": "OnlyOnFailure",
                "emailRecipients": "release.environment.owner;release.creator",
                "skipArtifactsDownload": false,
                "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
                "enableAccessToken": false,
                "publishDeploymentStatus": true,
                "badgeEnabled": false,
                "autoLinkWorkItems": false,
                "pullRequestDeploymentEnabled": false
            },
            "demands": [],
            "conditions": [],
            "executionPolicy": {
                "concurrencyCount": 1,
                "queueDepthCount": 0
            },
            "schedules": [],
            "owner": {
        "displayName": "{user name}",
        "id": "{user id}",
        "isContainer": false,
        "uniqueName": "{creator account}",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/"
      },
            "retentionPolicy": {
                "daysToKeep": 30,
                "releasesToKeep": 3,
                "retainBuild": true
            },
            "processParameters": {},
            "properties": {
                "BoardsEnvironmentType": {
                    "$type": "System.String",
                    "$value": "unmapped"
                },
                "LinkBoardsWorkItems": {
                    "$type": "System.String",
                    "$value": "False"
                }
            },
            "preDeploymentGates": {
                "id": 0,
                "gatesOptions": null,
                "gates": []
            },
            "postDeploymentGates": {
                "id": 0,
                "gatesOptions": null,
                "gates": []
            },
            "environmentTriggers": [],
            "badgeUrl": "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/{project name}/Release/badge/3c3xxx6414512/2/3"
        },

Here has some key parameters you need pay attention: id, owner, rank and conditions.
id: This is the stage id you specified to stage, its value must less than 1. Any value that less than 1 is okay here.
owner: This is required. Or you will receive the message that notify you the stage must has owner.
rank: The natural numbers greater than 1. This should be unique.
conditions: This is the one which you can configure which stage the current new one will depend on. The nutshell is it used to specify stage execution location of release.
Or you can copy the existing stage value in the response of Step1. And then you can change the corresponding parameters.
Result:

